# Potential form verbs followed by adjectives to end a sentence have to be in te form?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, て-form, i-adjectives

Do potential verbs followed by adjectives ending a sentence have to be in te form?

For example

> 見られて嬉しい

instead of

> 見られる嬉しい.

Comment: What context are you thinking of? Your samples are in the passive conjugation, not the potential. The potential for 見る is 見える.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Aren't the passive and potential the same for 見る since it's an ichidan verb? 見える and 見られる as potential would be used in different situations.

Comment: @Leebo — That’s why I ask for more context — 見える is unambiguously potential, whereas 見られる parses to me (when appearing in isolation like this) as passive. But as you note, usage depends on context.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Sorry for the slightly off-topic discussion, but my impression is that e.g. 富士山が見えて嬉しい would mean something like "I'm glad we were able to see Mount Fuji [because the weather conditions allowed it]" whereas with 見られて it could also mean something like "I'm glad I had the opportunity to see Mount Fuji". (Actually, without context 見られて here looks to me like potential rather than passive — simply because "I'm glad I had the opportunity to see [...]" seems a more common thing to say than "I'm glad [so.] saw me".) I view 見る as having two potential forms whose usage depends on context.

Comment: @Earthliŋ, I betray my bias of 東北弁, where the ~られる forms are less commonly used for potential. This is a useful thread for me to re-標準語-ize. 

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [potential form in *te*-form] + [*i*-adjective] is a common pattern. For example

> 逢えて嬉しい（です）
> I'm glad we met / I'm glad we were able to meet

> 消防車に乗れて楽しかった（です）
> Being able to get on a fire truck was fun

From a grammatical point of view, you cannot combine a verb in its basic form (e.g. 見られる) with an *i*-adjective / adjectival verb (e.g. 嬉しい). You could nominalize the verb (e.g. 見られるのは嬉しい), but it would read like a general statement, like "I enjoy being watched" (if 見られる is passive) or "I enjoy being able to see [new things, say]" (if 見られる is the potential form), but the latter is maybe not as natural as one would usually use the standard form rather than the potential form.

Using the *te*-form shows that the verbs happened in sequence, giving a notion of causality, like

> 見られて嬉しい
> (lit.) I was able to see and then (or rather because of it) I'm happy now
> I'm glad [that/because] I was able to see [it]