# What does 会えて mean?

Tags: meaning

What does 会えて mean?

また会えて嬉しいよ。

Looks like that 会えて is a some form of 会う (to meet), but the question is, what form? Jisho doesn't recognise the word “会えて”.

Answer (score 2):

It's the te-form of 会える, which is the potential form of 会う. The potential form by itself conjugates like an ichidan verb.

- 会う to meet
- 会える can meet
- 会えて te-form of 会える

See also: [Potential form verbs followed by adjectives to end a sentence have to be in te form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83291/5010)

Answer (score 2):

It's the potential form, meaning "can meet" or "is able to meet".

See [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/japanese-expressions-of-ability-and-potential-4070918) for a reference on the conjugation. It states:

> U-verbs: replace the final "~u" with "~eru".

So, where "また会って嬉しいよ。" means "It was great to see you again.", "また会えて嬉しいよ。" has more of a nuance of "It was great to have the opportunity to see you again."